# How can I remove the death counter on my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to remove the death counter at the top of the tab menu and also remove the death counter at the side of the screen. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about some scoreboard objective that is tracking deaths that you want removed?

Answer (score 1):

First, you would need to get the name of the objective. You can get the list of names of the created objectives in your world by running the `/scoreboard objectives list` command.

You would then remove the said scoreboard objective using the `/scoreboard objectives remove <objective>` command, `<objective>` being the name of the scoreboard objective.

If you only want the objective to not display in the sidebar or the player tab, you could run `/scoreboard objectives setdisplay <slot>`, `<slot>` being `sidebar`, or `list`